# SQL Server : order of operations not being followed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, smalldatetime

[Running SQL Server 2008 SP3]

I have a query which results in the overflow of a `smalldatetime` type. However, this should (in theory) never happen, due to the way I have the query structured - the logic should cause the truth value to be known long before the `DATEADD()` is executed which causes the overflow.

Here is the relevant part of the WHERE clause:

```
TimeIn >= '1/8/1950' AND TimeIn < '1/9/1950' AND
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1/8/1950', '9/14/2014'), TimeIn) >= '9/14/2014'
```

This works great - except when TimeIn (a `smalldatetime`) is >= 10/1/2014, then it will overflow the smalldatetime space.  But why does `DATEADD()` even get executed? if the date is 10/1/14, it *should* never be executed... but it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portions of a `WHERE` criteria aren't executed in a defined order that prevents your `DATEADD()` from executing, that's just not how SQL Server works.

I don't actually see an error when I run your query with the problematic date hard coded, but one way around this would be to use a `CASE` expression:

```
TimeIn >= '1/8/1950' AND TimeIn < '1/9/1950' 
AND CASE WHEN TimeIn >= '1950-01-08' AND TimeIn < '1950-01-09' 
         THEN DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1/8/1950', '9/14/2014'), TimeIn) 
    END >= '2014-09-14'
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. Any suggestions for a(n elegant) way around this?

Comment: I actually don't see what the problem is, you said it occurs when the date is after `10/1/2014` but the following seems to run fine:  `SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, '1/8/1950', '9/14/2014'), '10/2/2014')`

Comment: You can try parentheses around each expression part and hope SQL will short-cut it, but there is no guarantee as to how the optimizer will evaluate the query

Comment: @GoatCO yes your example works. But in my (larger) query, the SQL interpreter is deciding to keep the intermediate result in a `smalldatetime`.  If you wrap your above `DATEADD()` in a `CAST(<expr> AS smalldatetime)` then you see the problem.

Comment: @Conrad Ah, well instead of the `CASE` statement you could `CAST()` to a different datatype the offending field, not sure which is simpler.